# How can I apply scheduler in postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, odoo

I am having a **sale_order** table in postgres. Table has one column naming **invoice_status**. For that column possible values can be "upselling", "to invoice", "invoiced".

Problem occurs here, when new sale order gets placed in my case, it goes directly into "invoiced" state, Where I expect that it's value should be "to invoice". So is there any scheduler like thing in postgres, that will change the state to "to invoice" state from "invoiced" state as soon as new order comes(new record added in this column). I am not having that much deep idea about database. Help appreciated.

Comment: Use enum and default value.

Comment: That is cleary business logic of the application (Odoo) above the db layer. Why should you change that in database? Change that behaviour in Odoo. Why do you even need that requirement? There should be enough other data to know if the order was never invoiced.

Comment: Yes, but my database is synced with wordpress site. Any order got placed from wordpress site, should be queued there in odoo as sales order, but it goes in invoiced state directly.

Comment: Hm, but for me it's still business logic of Odoo, which should be changed/extended. Database syncing can be a really big security hole. Why don't you use Odoo's external API or Wordpress' API (if there is one) to exchange order values?

Answer (score 2):

Set default value as `to invoice` for the column `invoice_status`. So when new record is inserted the value for `invoice_status` will be `to invoice`, if no value for the column is given while creating.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name [SET DEFAULT value]
```

I think this is enough to satisfy your query. Else if you need a trigger, you can create a trigger after insert.

`https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql-triggers.php`

Answer (score 1):

For your problem, only a trigger is sufficient.

Although postgresql has a scheduler pgAgent.